# UIBarButtonItem not sending to action

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I've been over this forum looking at similar posts.  I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.  Please help me see it.  The button appears, but the action btnClicked is not getting called.

*.m

```
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"\u2699" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnClicked:)];
navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myButton;
```

In the same class I have the action method:

```
   -(void)btnClicked:(id)sender {
       NSLog(@"Hello World");
   }
```

*.h

```
    -(void) btnClicked:(id)sender;
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found(kind of) found the problem.  Somewhere in my xib it must be defining a layer or view that is over the button and not allowing the button to be pressed.  I moved the button to the left side and now it works.  I guess the moral of the story is: if your code looks right, verify that a UIView is not on top of the button.

cheers.